# Python Cookies in Requests - Grabbing Session Id

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to grab the cookies from a website in a requests so I can use it in my headers.  I was able to print the cookie but I can't use find() to save just the "Session-Id" to my headers

Here is the code

```
import requests


url = "WEBSITE-URL"
r = requests.get(url).cookies
print(r)
```

Now the output is like this

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie Session-Id=YK9Ox7Zop04blxaps2LlogAGFE5 for .website.com/>, <Cookie Version=default for website.com/>]>
```

How can I grab just the "Session-Id" part of this output.  I tried a few different things but it keeps throwing me error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests.get(url).cookies` returns a list of all cookies set by the website. If you wat to access the first cookie you can do it like this:

```py
import requests


url = "WEBSITE-URL"
r = requests.get(url).cookies
print(r[0])
```

If you want to access a specific value (in your case the Session-Id) from this cookie you can do that like this:

```py
import requests


url = "WEBSITE-URL"
r = requests.get(url).cookies
print(r.get_dict()['Session-Id'])
```

Comment: Doesn't work.   Throws the error 'KeyError: 'name=0, domain=None, path=None''  It is very difficult to grab something out of a cookie response for some reason :/

Comment: Does `print(r.items()[0].Session-Id)` instead of `print(r[0].Session-Id)` work?

Comment: Nope :/  It gives "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Session'  I see what you're trying to do and it makes no sense that it doesn't work.  Also strange something as simple as find() doesn't work.

Comment: `r.get_dict()['Session-Id']` could also work.

Comment: That did the trick!  It didn't include "Session-Id=" with it but it printed the actual ID after which is what's important.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

- **method 1：**

use selenium+phantomjs no interface access url, then get cookie value：

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
#url="https://et.xiamenair.com/xiamenair/book/findFlights.action?lang=zh&tripType=0&queryFlightInfo=XMN,PEK,2018-01-15"
url = "https://www.bing.com/"
driver.get(url)
# get cookie list
cookie_list=driver.get_cookies()
# format print cookie
for cookie in cookie_list:
    cookie_dict[cookie['name']]=cookie['value']
```

- **method 2：**

use cookielib：

（1）Python2

```
import cookielib
import urllib2
# Url = "https://et.xiamenair.com/xiamenair/book/findFlights.action?lang=zh&tripType=0&queryFlightInfo=XMN,PEK,2018-01-15"
Url = "https://www.bing.com/"
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(Url)
for index, cookie in enumerate(cj):
    print '[',index, ']',cookie
```

（2）Python3

```
from urllib import request
from http import cookiejar

# skip SSL verify
import ssl
# set ignore ssl verify
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # define cookiejar object
    cookie = cookiejar.CookieJar()
    # urllib.request HTTPCookieProcessor CookieHandler
    handler=request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie)
    # from CookieHandler create opener
    opener = request.build_opener(handler)
    # open url
    response = opener.open('http://www.baidu.com')
    # print cookie
    for item in cookie:
        print('Name = %s' % item.name)
        print('Value = %s' % item.value)
```

- **method 3：**

use requests：

Python3

```
def getCookie():
    url = "****"
    Hostreferer = {
        # 'Host':'***',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'
    }
    # urllib requests
    html = requests.get(url, headers=Hostreferer,verify=False)
    # cookie:DZSW_WSYYT_SESSIONID
    if html.status_code == 200:
        print(html.cookies)
        for cookie in html.cookies:
            print(cookie)
```

Comment: The problem still remains though.  It prints out more then just Session-Id.  I need to grab the Session-Id response from it.